# Android - In App Purchase: How to set button visibility on app start for non-consumable

Tags: android, android-layout, button, in-app-purchase

I am trying to see how to query/verify that an item is purchased upon the start of the app in order to change the UI/layout.

I've followed 2 IAP tutorials and have successfully created an In App Purchase button for a non consumable.

So far when the dummy purchase is completed the button disappears so the user can no longer see or purchase the item after using set visibility.

```html
if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

My current problem is that once the app is closed and reopened the purchaseButton is visible again. The app recognizes the item is already purchased so if the button is clicked again it will disappear.

What I would like to know is how to implement something where it will verify/query the purchase when the app starts so the button will no longer appear after the purchase